# Make element draggable when child element is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have multiple programmatically created span elements designed to look and act like windows. Each element has a title bar running across the top. I am trying to get it so that the draggability is activated either by or only if the mouse is over the child title element using jQuery UI, is this possible?

Comment: use .setDragImage (talking about native drag-n-drop, not jquery things), set the title as draggable and set the drag image as the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. When the mouse hold the child element, make the parent element draggable, then make it not draggable again when mouse realizes it.

```js
 // The parent element
var $aa = $("#aa"),
 // The child element  
  $bb = $("#bb");

// When the mouse is down
$bb.mousedown(function() {
    // Drag the element
    $aa.draggable();
});

// When the mouse realizes
$bb.mouseup(function() {
    // Don't drag the element
    $aa.draggable('destroy');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xI/qyl9vpwWFOXz7+x/9WkG5j/SVnSw21viy8fWwbeE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="aa">
  ---
  <div id="bb">Push me</div>
</div>
```

This could improve with more events, anyway.